# HAProxy how to detect url is IP address instead of domain name

Tags: redirect, haproxy

I want to redirect to `http://domainname` if user types `http://ip address`. What would be the `frontend` rule?

For example, this rule can find out if www is prefixed to a domain and if not redirect to www.domain.com.

```
http-request redirect code 301 location      \
  http://www.%[hdr(host)]%[capture.req.uri]  \
  unless { hdr_beg(host) -i www }
```

Similarly, I want to redirect to www.domain.com when user types IP address in browser.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since `user types IP address in browser`, this may work:

```
 http-request redirect code 301 location http://www.example.com%[capture.req.uri] if { hdr_reg(host) -i 127.0.0.1|192.168.1.100 }`
```

but it fails if user specifies `Host: example.com`

Comment: Just to clarify:
 This code when put under your frontend, Redirects the IP of server/Localhost to the FQDN.

User types  `192.168.1.100 ` > gets redirect to> `example.com`

Answer (score 0):

You can check the Host header value to see if it matches a regular expression that's roughly an IP address, something like:

```
acl ACL_IS_IP hdr(host) -i -m reg (\d+)\.(\d+)\.(\d+)\.(\d+)
http-request redirect code 301 location https://www.example.com/ if ACL_IS_IP
```